# Can "pigtail" be insulting in certain context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm Chinese. Manchurian regime (Qing dynasty, 1644~1911) used to enforce their hair style upon all Chinese men, which looks like the middle one in [this picture](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T0U80ytJ6h4/U-xcMs0HSGI/AAAAAAAAAhQ/Aryhp1G007Y/w1200-h630-p-nu/Chinese_Men_Hair.jpg).

I know it's called "pigtail" in verbal English, but I've read historical stories about Westerners & Japanese mocking Chinese people with the word "pigtail" back then. It does sound unfriendly in some sense because "pig" is not a compliment in most cultures. However, I don't find the word insulting by any English dictionary.

So my question is, can "pigtail" be insulting in certain context, like referring to the Qing Chinese hair style in the age of imperialism? Or it's totally a misunderstanding across cultures? Could it offend other people besides Chinese who have read those stories?

Comment: [**pigtail, pig-tail**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pigtail%22+%22usually+a+derogatory%22) *Usually a derogatory reference to a Chinese or Chinese American. It alludes to the once-customary tightly braided hair worn by the Chinese. The term is found in many old children's rhymes or taunts of the nineteenth century.* I doubt many of those who use[d] it (who will span many cultures, applying it to various targets) would have any thought of ***pig** = [dirty] swine*. But IT WILL OBVIOUSLY OFFEND!

Comment: Absolutely everything can be insulting in some context.

Comment: In the US, the word *pigtail* for a hair style refers to various ways of gathering hair, usually but not always involving braiding. It carries no meaning of invidious porcine comparison and is applied to people of all races. Given anything you care to name, you can always find someone  will take offense at that thing in some context. There is nothing that cannot generate misunderstanding "across cultures".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I doubt the epithet *pigtail* has been used much in the US since the repeal of the Chinese Exclusion Act.  It's use to describe hair in the US isn't insulting except as Jim noted.

Comment: Pigtails in reference to hair, at least in the U.S. normally means two braids or hanks of hair https://www.google.com/search?q=pigtails&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=904&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5uoX73K3PAhVrw4MKHUZfC14Q_AUIBigB&dpr=1, and almost always girls or women.  Only one tail present would normally be called a pony tail.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Surely a pigtail is plaited (braided in Am E) and tied off at the bottom; but a pony tail is just held together with a ribbon, elastic band or something similar at the top and the rest of the hair hangs loose.

Comment: @BoldBen:  Not in common usage.  Check the link for pigtails in the other comment and then ponytail (https://www.google.com/search?q=ponytail&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=904&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc35Lk463PAhVBwYMKHbKfCqMQ_AUIBigB)

Comment: I agree with @AbraCadaver.  I have heard "pigtails" (for two short "tails") since I was a child in the 50s, and it never carried a derogatory connotation (except when boys were teasing other boys, in the days when "normal" boys did not wear long hair).

Comment: The Chinese hairstyle is more properly (or formally) called a ***queue*** http://asianhistory.about.com/od/glossaryps/g/What-Is-A-Queue.htm

Comment: @AbraCadaver Must be a difference between Br E & Am E. I don't believe a single pigtail or 'plait' would be called a pony tail here. The unplaited pairs would be called 'bunches' and only plaited pairs called pigtails or plaits.Would you consider a single [French Plait](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=french+plait&client=tablet-android-pega&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhndWhiq7PAhXFrxoKHR6eCVIQ_AUIBygB&biw=960&bih=600) to be a pony tail?

Comment: In AmE, 'pigtail' is a way girls wear their hair, in two small bunches, usually unbraided, to the sides. A 'ponytail' is one big bunch in the back. Adult women normally don't wear pigtails (it's a style usually only used by younger girls. A big bunch on the side... I wouldn't know what to call it. In AmE neither currently have any association with foreigners. So it may very well have derogatory connotations when used against someone of Asian descent, but to most AmE speakers it wouldn't be understood that way.

Comment: @deadrat: Putting aside the question of exactly which *hairstyle* the term may denote, I think we can take it for granted that using it to identify ***people within a cultural group*** would almost always be offensive (as with *raghead, towelhead* etc., which are obviously far more common today). But exactly how common it is, or *how* offensive, are matters of opinion (which is the reason for my closevote).

Comment: It should be noted that "pigtail" is a "term of the art" in wiring contexts, where wire ends are "stripped" of insulation, twisted together, and joined with solder or a "wire nut".

Answer (score 3):

A pigtail is not insulting in current BE. It is not used as a racial epithet. It is simply a valid description of a hairstyle. In the 18th and 19th centuries British soldiers and sailors used to wear their hair in a pigtail.

Prior to the early 20th century, in the morals of the day, it was simply casual speech - an informal reference to a group of people - any insult would come from the context, rather than the word itself:

> **2b. colloquial (frequently derogatory and offensive). A person who wears a pigtail, esp. a Chinese person. *Now rare or historical*.**
>
> 1886   Cornhill Mag. July 55   *Sweetmeats..being great favourites with the ‘pigtails’.*

The OED gives some of the history:

> **2.a. A plait or tail of hair. In early use: a single plait or queue of hair hanging down from the back of the head, as in a particular style of wig, or as worn by soldiers and sailors in the late 18th and early 19th centuries; a long plait of hair as formerly worn by the Chinese. Now chiefly: each of two tails of (usually plaited) hair hanging from either side of the head, as worn esp. by young girls.**
>
> 1991   Hair's How No. 34. 808/2   D*ivide the ponytail in two, then plait to form two pigtails.*

(A ponytail differs in that it is not plaited.)

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, can "pigtail" be insulting in certain context, like referring to the Qing Chinese hair style in the age of imperialism?

The short answer is "yes." The more "adult" or "encyclopedic" word for the Qing hairstyle would be [*queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(hairstyle)).

Notice that the *word "pigtail" itself* is not problematic at all; it's certainly fine to say to a little girl, "I like your pigtails." But in the context of Qing China, it's basically the same as if one were to use a word like "dress" or "skirt" to refer to a [changshan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changshan) (as opposed to using the Chinese word itself, or a less feminizing word such as "robe"). The problem here is that we're taking an unfamiliar or exotic concept from a foreign culture and mapping it onto a concept that is undignified (in this case, [both infantilizing and feminizing](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GirlishPigtails)) in our home culture.

Note that our "home culture" in this case is *21st-century*; we have different cultural reference points for hairstyles (Pippi Longstocking, Britney Spears) than someone from the 1920s, so the words we use (or avoid) are naturally going to be different from theirs.

[Google Ngrams for "his pigtail", "her pigtails"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+pigtail%2Cher+pigtail%2Chis+pigtails%2Cher+pigtails&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) — I have no neat narrative to fit onto this, but you can see "pigtails" becoming a girl thing in the mid-20th century and the frequency of "his pigtail" dropping off.

Still, even back then, the infantilizing associations of "pigtail" in an Asian context might be demonstrated by [*The Mikado*'s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mikado) lyrics:

[image]

> I seized him by his little pig-tail
> And on his knees fell he,
> As he squirmed and struggled
> And gurgled and guggled,
> I drew my snickersnee!

(Of course the *actual* Japanese of Gilbert's time didn't wear Qing Chinese hairstyles, but Gilbert didn't necessarily know that, and certainly didn't care, as far as the lyrics were concerned. Note both the "*little* pig-tail" and Ko-Ko's "snickersnee" as opposed to "sword." The description here is deliberately childish for comic effect; it would ruin the intended effect entirely if Ko-Ko said "I seized him by the hair and drew my sword.")

TLDR if you're translating a Chinese story and it refers to a male character's 辫子, you may save yourself some embarrassment by translating it "queue" instead of "pigtail."